# Convert int to single byte in a string?

Tags: python

I'm implementing PKCS#7 padding right now in Python and need to pad chunks of my file in order to amount to a number divisible by sixteen. I've been recommended to use the following method to append these bytes:

```
input_chunk += '\x00'*(-len(input_chunk)%16)
```

What I need to do is the following:

```
input_chunk_remainder = len(input_chunk) % 16
input_chunk += input_chunk_remainder * input_chunk_remainder
```

Obviously, the second line above is wrong; I need to convert the first `input_chunk_remainder` to a single byte string. How can I do this in Python?

Comment: Are you sure you want to implement this yourself? Does [`pycrypto`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto) or one of the OpenSSL wrappers not already do what you want? For crypto-related code, it's much more important than usual to be absolutely sure the code does what you think it does, and that's a lot easier when someone else has written it and a thousand major projects are testing it every day…

Comment: Padding is not so difficult, it's just to ensure that the length of the input is a multiple of 16.

Comment: Sure, but presumably your actual end goal involves more than just padding…

Comment: The end goal uses PyCrypto ;)

Comment: And PyCrypto doesn't have a way to pad PKCS#7?

Comment: If you can find it, link it. It doesn't seem that it does, from a quick search through their documentation. They also don't support AES EAX or GCM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python 3, you can create bytes of a given numeric value with the [`bytes()` type](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#bytes); you can pass in a list of integers (between 0 and 255):

```
>>> bytes([5])
b'\x05'
bytes([5] * 5)
b'\x05\x05\x05\x05\x05'
```

An alternative method is to use an [`array.array()`](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html) with the right number of integers:

```
>>> import array
>>> array.array('B', 5*[5]).tobytes()
b'\x05\x05\x05\x05\x05'
```

or use the [`struct.pack()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) to pack your integers into bytes:

```
 >>> import struct
 >>> struct.pack('{}B'.format(5), *(5 * [5]))
 b'\x05\x05\x05\x05\x05'
```

There may be more ways.. :-)

In Python 2 (ancient now), you can do the same by using the [`chr()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr):

```
>>> chr(5)
'\x05'
>>> chr(5) * 5
'\x05\x05\x05\x05\x05'
```

Comment: SERIOUSLY outdated, this works only in python-2 (...should let it as it it, to discover cheating in the interviews :-)

Comment: @ankostis: it's not *that* outdated. Yes, this was written for Python 2, but Python 3 still has `struct.pack()` and `bytearray()` and `array.array()`. However, the cleanest method would be to use `bytes([5] * 5)`. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Python3, the `bytes` built-in accepts a sequence of integers. So for just one integer:

```
>>> bytes([5])
b'\x05'
```

Of course, thats bytes, not a string. But in Python3 world, OP would probably use bytes for the app he described, anyway.

Comment: This is just what I needed; thanks!